Origen del nombre ‘colón’ (pan)
Según el prestigioso Diccionario del Español Actual, de la Fundación BBVA:

colón1
m
1
Unidad monetaria de Costa Rica.
2
Unidad monetaria de El Salvador anterior a la implantación del dólar en 2001.
colón2
m
Pieza de pan candeal de forma alargada.
colón3 –na
adj
(col) [Pers.] que se cuela o pasa furtivamente o con habilidad. Tb n.

Distingue tres etimologías para colón. La primera es fácil, viene del nombre de Cristóbal Colón. La tercera también se deduce trivialmente, del verbo colarse.
Pero qué hay de la segunda? Según lo que estuve buscando es parte de la jerga que usan en España para referirse al pan candeal peroooo... por qué divide una nueva etimología? Tiene o no tiene que ver el nombre del pan con Cristóbal Colón?

@Sofronias son etimologías, banana. Buscá otras palabras como "pico" (lo que deberías cerrar) y vas a ver qué también aparecen tres etimologías, donde cada una aparece con su juego de acepciones. Y es lo mismo, se le dice diccionario de la Fundación BBVA porque es la página en donde aparece. Si vas a venir a joder rajá de acá.

@Sofronias son diferentes etimologías, salamín. Qué te pensás, que es casualidad que pongan superíndices al lado de la palabra y que armen diferentes secciones agrupando definiciones en común de acuerdo al superíndice que aparece al lado de la palabra, en lugar de escribir todas las definiciones juntas? Dejá de romper los huevos y compará lo que hace el DLE con los superíndices en pico y después revisá pico en el otro diccionario. Preguntate si es casualidad lo de los superíndices. Y cerrá el pico, gil.

@Sofronias Seguro que sí. El que supuestamente perora por el uso del diccionario ‘para ampliar el léxico’ resulta ser que no sabe cómo usarlo. Imposible caer más bajo que eso.

Quizás tenga relación, como aumentativo (¿quizás festivo?), con la palabra colín:

m. Esp. Pieza de pan habitualmente cilíndrica, muy delgada y crujiente.
Sin.: grisín, pico1, palito, palitroque, regañá, regañada.

que aparece ya en el DLE en 1970 como 2ª acepción:

Barrita de pan larga y del grueso de un dedo.

Mientras que, para colón el DLE solo recoge, a día de hoy, la acepción:

m. Unidad monetaria de Costa Rica y de El Salvador.

y solo es en otros diccionarios, como el de Manuel Seco, donde se recoge la acepción por la que se pregunta:

Pieza de pan candeal de forma alargada.

Por supuesto también es posible la hipótesis opuesta: que preexistiera la acepción  de colón por la que se pregunta, sin recoger en el DLE, y que a partir de ésta, surgiera como diminutivo (¿jocoso?) la forma colín que sí entró en el DLE hace más de 50 años, pero esta segunda hipótesis me parece menos verosímil.

Se asume que este tipo de pan fue nombrado en honor a Cristóbal Colón.
Durante sus viajes, Colón y su tripulación llevaron consigo alimentos que pudieran durar mucho tiempo sin estropearse, y el pan colón, con su textura y durabilidad, se convirtió en un alimento básico en sus expediciones.

@Sofronias a ver? dónde aparece?

@Sofronias AA no sabés, salame.

@Sofronias Nono ahora respondé vos ya que tanto venís a caretearla y a hacerte el que sabés.
